# LdapContext.search() not returning custom Active Directory attributes

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

I want to query for Active Directory user attributes, including a custom attribute. I am receiving the built-in attributes fine, but the custom attribute in the `Attributes` object is null. I know it is there and that it is set, because I got the equivalent to work in a PowerShell program.

Here is what I am doing:

```
SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
String[] attrIDs = { "distinguishedName", "mail", "mycustomattribute"};
constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search("DC=mydomain,DC=lan", "sAMAccountName="
        + user, constraints);
if (answer.hasMore())
{
    Attributes attrs = answer.next().getAttributes();
    System.out.println("distinguishedName "+ attrs.get("distinguishedName"));
    System.out.println("mail "+ attrs.get("mail"));
    System.out.println("custom "+ attrs.get("mycustomattribute"));
}
```

This correctly outputs the distinguished name and the mail, but it outputs null for the custom attribute.

I had tested first with PowerShell to make sure the attribute was set properly. I did a `$user = Get-ADUser ...`, then output `$user.mycustomattribute` and got the expected value. I need this value in my Java app.

Here is my thought process so far...

Do custom attributes need to be accessed differently? I'm not sure, but a Google query doesn't bring up anything that suggests so.

Could this have anything to do with the domain controller queried not having that data? When setting up the `LdapContext` object I do have `hashtable.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");` for the environment properties, so I'm guessing that rules that out.

I just realized that, if I use ADSI Edit (an MS tool browsing the data), the custom attribute shows up as `<not set>` if I run it as a non-domain-admin user, but if I run it as a domain admin, it shows the attribute correctly in ADSI Edit. I thought I had figured it out, so I ran the Java app as a domain admin, but it still does not work (gets other attributes but not the custom one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured this out, and I feel slightly like a dunce.

When I ran ADSI Edit and it would not give me the correct value unless I was running it as a domain admin, I thought that was the answer, and it was, but I was trying to fix it by running *my program* as an admin. I was still supplying non-admin credentials to the domain controller in my context's environment.

```
hashtable.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "non-admin account");
```

When it should have been

```
hashtable.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin account");
```

So the underlying problem was that I did not have permission to read the custom attributes that I was searching for. I thought that the attributes were readable by everyone (in fact, I was told as much by the network/AD administrators who set it up, otherwise I would have checked that earlier), but in fact they were not.

Moral: Don't always trust the environment conditions that are provided to you. I spent almost two days of my time because I didn't question the config the network admins provided. (No hard feelings though, I make mistakes too.)